# python : how to run the function if there are data changes in the mysql database

Tags: python, mysql

I have a problem to run the python function automatically if there are data changes, such as decreasing or increasing the amount of data in the database

I'm still a beginner in Python, and don't know what I should do like the problem above. and hope someone can help to solve the problem. thank you

Comment: Mysql does not have a notification feature, so you need to either regularly poll the database and check for changes (simple code, but not too efficient) or you need to implement the notification feature yourself using compiled UDFs in mysql (very, very complex code and no-one has done it before as far as I know)

Comment: You can create another function which keeps the track of data in the database, whenever that data increases or decreases, that function can call your main function(the function you are talking about).